# Finiteness of models around a non-pseudo-effective ray

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, minimal-model-program

Let $(X,\Delta) $ a klt pair and $\rho $ a numerical class of divisor that is not contained in the pseudo-effective cone. Let $(X,\Delta_i)$ be a sequence of klt pairs such that $K_X+\Delta_i$ is not pseudo-effective, and such sequence converge in the Neron-Severi to $\rho $.

Can the Mori fiber spaces of $(X,\Delta_i)$ be a infinite sequence of models that do not differ by Sarkisov links?

I made a major edit to this question, because the way I wrote it the first time was trivially false.

Comment: you should define what you mean by birational model

Comment: I made a major edit to the question, I hope now it makes more sense.